# DataGridView problem when adding columns

Tags: windows, forms, datagridview

Hey guys! First time I use Visual Studio 2008 Windows Form Application with C++.

I want to put a dataGridView on my form. That is ok. But when adding one column, on the gridView appear 2 columns. First with no header (which I dont want) and the second is ok(my column). I tried to set the column number from code, but the same thing happens.

Any idea to solve this?

Thanks,
 Andrew

```
// 
        // table
        // 
        this->table->AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        this->table->AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
        this->table->ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System::Windows::Forms::DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode::AutoSize;
        this->table->Columns->AddRange(gcnew cli::array< System::Windows::Forms::DataGridViewColumn^  >(1) {this->Column1});
        this->table->Location = System::Drawing::Point(13, 89);
        this->table->Name = L"table";
        this->table->ReadOnly = true;
        this->table->Size = System::Drawing::Size(240, 150);
        this->table->TabIndex = 2;
        // 
        // Column1
        // 
        this->Column1->HeaderText = L"Column1";
        this->Column1->Name = L"Column1";
        this->Column1->ReadOnly = true;
```

Comment: Can you post a simple example?

Comment: I have edited my post and add the sample code

Comment: could you please tag the question with the language. It looks like c++

Comment: Hi Andrew - I don't think there's enough info in your snippet to determine exactly what's going wrong - could you post a larger snippet - one which I could copy and paste and try to run for myself?

Answer (score 0):

Are you adding the column in the constructor?

I've had a problem in the past where items added in the constructor get added twice, because (I think) the constructor gets called to make the control appear in the designer view, (which then gets added to the instance) and then again when you run your program.

If that is what's happening for you, you need to check that you aren't in design mode.

There are a few different ways to check this, depending on context - see [How to tell if .NET code is being run by Visual Studio designer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73515/how-to-tell-if-net-code-is-being-run-by-visual-studio-designer)

Comment: It happens both at runtime and in the form designer(runned from 2 different projects).