# How do I execute a line conditionally in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'd like the line to execute when running within Visual Studio but not when the exe is running stand alone.

Thanks.

Comment: in which context do you want to run which line of code?

Comment: Do you mean to only execute the line in debug mode?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you mean when a debugger is attached? If so, you could do something like this:

```
#if DEBUG
if (Debugger.IsAttached)
{
    //Your code here
}
#endif
```

This will only run when the debugger is attached, such as running with F5. Double clicking it or using Ctrl+F5 won't cause the `if` statement to be hit. It's also wrapped in a conditional so then when you compile to release the code is not even there.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the build flags

```
#if DEBUG
      //do something in here
#endif
```

And then when you build in release those things won't happen.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ConditionalAttribute`. Put the code you want to execute conditionally in a method, and mark the method with `[Conditional("DEBUG")]`. The method and the call to it will only be compiled when the DEBUG constant is set.

Answer (score 1):

Try this thread:
[How to tell if .NET code is being run by Visual Studio designer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73515/how-to-tell-if-net-code-is-being-run-by-visual-studio-designer)

Answer (score 0):

I think this code may help:

```
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
private void DEBUG_Execute() 
{ 
    if (Debugger.IsAttached)
    { 
        //todo:  execute line when running within VS
    } 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can check the `Application.startuppath`

If you are in Debugging, that means **bin/Debug** folders are present  otherwise you are running the exe. In this way you can formulate the code.

Comment: That seems very fragile, and for web applications, there is no Debug / Release directory. Just bin.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the reply. But the OP did not mentioned ASP.net and I also have understood to use #if DEBUG
if (Debugger.IsAttached)
{
    //Your code here
}
#endif
because of less computations. In my case I was evaluating the Application.startuppath

Comment: Even in other project types, this `Debug` path is not guaranteed to be present, and from my experience scarcely is with professional project build plans. In short, this is an awful idea.