# How to know whether a control is at design-time or not?

Tags: c#, .net, design-time

I have a class (control), implementing ICustomTypeDescriptor, which is used both at design-time and run-time by PropertyGrid for customization. I need to expose different properties at design-time (standard controls properties like `width`, `height` and so on) and at run-time, when PropertyGrid is used in my program to change other properties of that control.

My code is like:

```
class MyControl : UserControl, ICustomTypeDescriptor
{
    //Some code..

    public PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(Attribute[] attributes)
    {
        return GetProperties();
    }

    public PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties()
    {
        //I need to do something like this:
        if (designTime)
        { //Expose standart controls properties
            return TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this, true);
        }
        else
        {
            //Forming a custom property descriptor collection
            PropertyDescriptorCollection pdc = new PropertyDescriptorCollection(null);
            //Some code..
            return pdc;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there an analog for a design-time flag in C#? Is it maybe better to use conditional compilation?

Comment: Are you talking about wpf or winform?

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[How to tell if .NET code is being run by Visual Studio designer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/73515/how-to-tell-if-net-code-is-being-run-by-visual-studio-designer)*.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Check if [DesignMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component.designmode.aspx) is true or false. It's a property that belongs to the control base class.

Comment: Actually, it belongs to the `System.ComponentModel.Component` base class.

Comment: `'Component.DesignMode' is inaccessible due to its protection level` How do I get around this error ?

Comment: @GuidoG Don't check the componet from the outside. The control has to check itself.

Answer (score 9):

The flag should be `DesignMode`. Hence your code should look as follows

```
public PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties()
{
   //I need to do something like this:
   if (this.DesignMode)
   { //Expose standart controls properties
       return TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this, true);
   }
   else
   {   //Forming a custom property descriptor collection
       PropertyDescriptorCollection pdc = new PropertyDescriptorCollection(null);
       //Some code..
       return pdc;      
   }
}
```

Here is the according [MSDN doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component.designmode.aspx).

Comment: I really hate redundant "this". :)

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`DesignMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component.designmode.aspx) property of the base. This will tell you about the mode.