# .NET Design View Not Running Windows Forms OnLoad

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

I have a windows application which works when the application is running, however in design view, the code in the OnLoad event crashes due to a host of reasons. Is there a way to do something like this:

```
private void WindowsForm_OnLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsDesignView())
        {
               // some code that breaks in design view but works normally
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the [DesignMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component.designmode.aspx) property inheritied from Component.

```
if(!this.DesignMode) {
    // Your stuff...
}
```

Though there is a better way to do it than that, since if I recall correctly, sometimes there can be issues with the `DesignMode` property.  I think I have some code somewhere, let me find it.

EDIT: Well, I can't find what I was thinking of, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73659/721276) discusses some of the downsides of `DesignMode` you should keep in mind, as well as a workaround for a specific issue.  However, the issue doesn't affect what you want to do here, it doesn't look like, but it's good to be aware of it anyway.

Comment: This does not work in constructor. Instead, `LicenseManager.UsageMode == LicenseUsageMode.Designtime;` must be used there.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use this:

```
if (!this.DesignMode)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [DesignMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component.designmode.aspx) property of the form.

```
if (!this.DesignMode)
{
    // Include code that breaks the designer here...
}
```