# Is it possible to detect d:DesignInstance

Tags: c#, wpf

I have some AOP going on in my data objects, and it's causing the Designer to fail when creating an object. Is it possible to detect that the object is being created from the designer so I can abort the AOP procedures?

Preferrably from within the AOP class (which is in a lib and doesn't even know WPF is involved.) Maybe by looking at the workdir (if it's different via the designer) or something like that?

```
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
mc:Ignorable="d" 
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance IsDesignTimeCreatable=True, Type={x:Type ui:DesignData}}"

class DesignData
{
    public DesignData()
    {
        Func<int, ObservableCollection<Food>> createFoods = i =>
            {
                var r = new ObservableCollection<Food>();
                for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                {
                    r.Add(new Food("Food #"+j+" for profile #"+i));
                }
                return r;
            };

        Profiles = new ObservableCollection<Profile>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            //Crashes because of AOP start-up procedure
            Profiles.Add(new Profile { Name = "ProfileName" + i, Foods = createFoods(i) });
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Profile> Profiles { get; set; }
}
```

If the answer is no, what's a suitable alternative? The only thing I can think of is creating a completely new data object with the same properties as the real one but that would be incredibly annoying.

Comment: Does this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/73515/8446 help?

Comment: @RogerLipscombe I detected the devenv process in the AOP lib and the Initial error (a serialization error) has now gone away but now I'm getting a dll-not-found error because the devenv workdir doesn't have access to the SQLite interop.. although I can't figure out why it'd even try to load that since the AOP logic is cut off before SQLite is even invoked.. I'll try some more things