# Is drawing to a minimized window outside WM_PAINT harmless?

Tags: winapi

As described on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/dd162492(v=vs.85).aspx), it is allowed to draw outside `WM_PAINT`. Does this also apply when the window is in minimized state?

I did some tests and `GetDC(hwnd)` returns a device context even when the window is minimized and drawing to it doesn't cause any problems, although in practice nothing is drawn of course because the window isn't visible.

This is perfectly fine with me. I'm only asking this question to learn whether it is harmless to draw to a minimized window outside `WM_PAINT` or whether I have to write code that checks if the window is minimized and doesn't draw in that case. If drawing to a minimized window is harmless, however, I can just skip writing such code.

Comment: It is harmless albeit pointless. You should be trying to avoid wasting cpu cycles on such futility.

Comment: The problem is that I need to draw to my backing store bitmap even when the window is minimized anyway. So the only actual window drawing is a single `BitBlt` or `StretchBlt` call from the backing store bitmap to the window DC. If `BitBlt` and `StretchBlt` boil down to a  `NOP` when the window is minimized, it's a waste of cpu cycles I can live with. The bigger waste is drawing to the backing store bitmap when minimized but I can't skip that because of my peculiar program design.

Comment: So it would be interesting to know if `StretchBlt` will actually do any stretching when used on a minimized window DC or whether such a call would just be a `NOP`...

Comment: ...because if it did any actual stretching then of course it would make sense to not call it on minimized window DCs to save cpu cycles.

Comment: You can't get a warranty here, you have to test.  This [*does* go wrong sometimes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26566254/17034) in unexpected ways, happens in C++ code as well.

Comment: Note that with the DWM it's not necessarily a no-op, since minimized windows can still be visible using Aero Peek or whatever it's called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can draw outside of WM paint. WM_PAINT is sent to your window to indicate that some areas of the Window must be redrawn.  For example when another window like a dialog box is popped on to of yours and then later removed.

There are many legitimate cases to draw outside of WM paint, for example you need to update an animation of some sort.

Just keep in mind that all drawing commands are subject to clipping regions outside of which they have no effect

Note this applies to drawing on actual windows, drawing on in memory bitmaps and printer contexts could be done any time.

Comment: Thanks, but see my original question again. The question is specifically about drawing outside `WM_PAINT` to windows **that are minimized**.

Comment: Are you drawing on the actual Window context or on the backing store that you are BitBlt to the window.   In former case the commands are ignored and in the later case you can safely do so.

Comment: I'm drawing to both. First I'm drawing to the backing store (which is a DIB section) and then I'm drawing the backing store to the window using either `BitBlt` or `StretchBlt` depending on whether the window dimensions match the backing store dimensions.

Comment: So first call doesn't care because it is not drawing on any actual window.  Second call will result into NOP.

Comment: Ok. And what about `StretchBlt`? Will it first compute the stretching and just skip the blitting or will the whole call be just a NOP because the window is minimized? If it computed the stretching in any case, it would make sense to not call it when the window is minimized to save cpu cycles. If the whole call is a NOP though then one could just call it without wasting too much cpu.

Comment: That depends on your actual setup.  Lots of these operations are done at the driver level and a lot of times by your graphics hardware with GDI just steering things around.

Comment: Good point, `StretchBlt` is of course something that is better done by the GPU. So I guess there is no general answer and the best way is to not draw to the window DC if it's minimized.

Answer (score -2):

It's very likely that a mature platform like Windows has code that is written defensively to block that sort of no-op. But the instructions say that drawing should be done only in response to a WM_PAINT message, and you should obey that. Otherwise you don't have a leg to stand on if the program develops a bug.

For hobby programming, that hardly matters. For commercial programming, it could mean the difference between being sued or not sued for damages.

Comment: See my original post again. MSDN explicitly says that drawing outside `WM_PAINT` is allowed.

Comment: What sort of bug do you have in mind that *"the program develops"*?

Comment: MS could release a new version of Windows on which the program behaves incorrectly. If not written according to instructions, you have no recourse against Microsoft and your own customers have recourse against you.

Comment: Microsoft cannot release a new version of Windows, where code written against the documented [contract](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/dd162492.aspx) suddenly breaks. Rendering outside a `WM_PAINT` message handler does not violate that contract.