# Detect if WPF application is running or in Visual Studio windows visualizer

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013

I have a WPF application which opens a popup when the main window is loaded. The problem is when I select the .xaml file in the solution explorer in Visual Studio 2013, **the popup "pops" even when the application is not running**. I suppose it is an intended behavior since the visualizer needs to execute the code in order to render the page layout, but for now I need to close it every time I load the page... I cannot temporarily disable this popup since it has some start logic for the application (selection of a location,...).

Here is the code of the popup trigger

```
public GeneralProcess() //usercontrol
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Loaded += GeneralProcess_Loaded;
}

void GeneralProcess_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var popup = new StationSelect();
    popup.Owner = Window.GetWindow(this);
    popup.ShowDialog();
}
```

Is there a way to know if the application is running or if I am in the visualizer, or is there a way to disable the `Loaded`event just for visual studio ? The goal is to still be able to see the page for easy editing.

**EDIT** : this question is a duplicate. However [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10725662/555111)  worked for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to tell if .NET code is being run by Visual Studio designer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73515/how-to-tell-if-net-code-is-being-run-by-visual-studio-designer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void GeneralProcess_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
        return;
    var popup = new StationSelect();
    popup.Owner = Window.GetWindow(this);
    popup.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work : `IsInDesignTool` is not defined. I'm in .NET 4.5. But nice approach, I'll search more on this DesignerProperties.

Comment: Thank you! For those who come here be sure to rebuild the project and reopen the .xaml files after doing this.